# I need to delete selected row from the datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to delete the selected row in the `DataGridView` from a database but I get a different index. Any suggestions where I'm doing something wrong?
[image]

```
private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell oneCell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
    {
        if (oneCell.Selected)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(oneCell.RowIndex);
            string deleteQuery = $"DELETE FROM {comboBox1.SelectedItem} WHERE id= " + oneCell.RowIndex;
            form1.conn = new SqlConnection($"Server = {form1.ServerBox.Text }; Database = { form1.DBBox.Text}; Trusted_Connection = True");
            form1.cmd = new SqlCommand(deleteQuery, form1.conn);
            form1.conn.Open();
            form1.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            form1.conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. usualy index in some list is not an id ... 2. how it can have index different than -1 if  this row is no longer in the grid?

Comment: What you are doing wrong is, you expect the rows index the be equal to the elements id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your approach is not correct as you are iterating through selected cells. What happens if you select more than one cells in a row. Will you delete this row twice?

I propose following:

```
private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedRows = dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().ToArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedRows.Length; i++)
    {
        if(selectedRows[i].Cells[idColumn.Index].Value is int id)
        {
            string deleteQuery = $"DELETE FROM {comboBox1.SelectedItem} WHERE id= " + id;
            form1.conn = new SqlConnection($"Server = {form1.ServerBox.Text }; Database = { form1.DBBox.Text}; Trusted_Connection = True");
            form1.cmd = new SqlCommand(deleteQuery, form1.conn);
            form1.conn.Open();
            form1.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            form1.conn.Close();
            dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(selectedRows[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the problem lies with your

```
dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(oneCell.RowIndex);
```

Here you seem to be deleting the row from the `DataGridView`. Therefore when you're trying to get the index from the cell with `oneCell.RowIndex` it is no longer in any row that's part of the `DataGridView` => `RowIndex -1`

Try deleting the `row` from the `DataGridView` **after** trying to access the index:

```
private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell oneCell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
    {
        if (oneCell.Selected)
        {
            string deleteQuery = $"DELETE FROM {comboBox1.SelectedItem} WHERE id= " + oneCell.RowIndex;
            form1.conn = new SqlConnection($"Server = {form1.ServerBox.Text }; Database = { form1.DBBox.Text}; Trusted_Connection = True");
            form1.cmd = new SqlCommand(deleteQuery, form1.conn);
            form1.conn.Open();
            form1.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            form1.conn.Close();

            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(oneCell.RowIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:
As others in the comments have already mentioned, it's probably not the best idea to use a `RowIndex` as an `id` for a database in the first place.

Comment: why it has -1 ? it at least resolve half of the problem

Comment: It misses the actual error... RowIndex != Element.Id in database. See coments above.

Comment: Well in OPs case `RowIndex` might actually be the database `id`. It wouldn't be a good design and not very reliable but it may be the case.